# What do I need to learn for solving these

Tags: passive-networks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwte6h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*The network 'N' contains only 2 elements. If the response for unit step excitation is i(t)= e^(-3t) A for t>=0. Determine  elements and their connections?*

What do I need to learn for cracking these types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Laplace transforms and control theory would be a good start. 
And so you know the box contains a pure delay. For a 3rad/s signal.